# R: Modifying Graphs

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, nodes

I posted a comment/reply to another stackoverflow post over here : [R: Understanding Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65243162/r-understanding-graph/65257889#65257889) relating to graphs in R.

If you create some data corresponding to movies and actors (in which movies can not be connected to other movies directly, and actors can not be connected to other actors directly), you write some R code to check if your graph is bipartite:

```
library(igraph)
film_data <- data.frame(
    
    "movie" = c("movie_1", "movie_1", "movie_1", "movie_2", "movie_2", "movie_2", "movie_3", "movie_3", "movie_3", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_5", "movie_5", "movie_5", "movie_6", "movie_6"),
    "actor" = c("actor_1", "actor_2", "actor_3", "actor_2", "actor_3", "actor_4", "actor_1", "actor_5", "actor_6", "actor_2", "actor_7", "actor_1", "actor_8", "actor_5", "actor_9", "actor_3", "actor_2", "actor_8")
)

#create directed graph 
graph <- graph.data.frame(film_data, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)
plot(graph)
```

[image]

```
V(graph)$type <- V(graph)$name %in% film_data[,1]
is.bipartite(graph)
[1] TRUE
```

However, you can "purposefully sabotage" this graph by adding a link between two actors (actor_2 and actor_3) so that the graph is no longer bipartite:

```
film_data <- data.frame(
    
    "movie" = c("movie_1", "movie_1", "movie_1", "movie_2", "movie_2", "movie_2", "movie_3", "movie_3", "movie_3", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_5", "movie_5", "movie_5", "movie_6", "movie_6", "actor_2"),
    "actor" = c("actor_1", "actor_2", "actor_3", "actor_2", "actor_3", "actor_4", "actor_1", "actor_5", "actor_6", "actor_2", "actor_7", "actor_1", "actor_8", "actor_5", "actor_9", "actor_3", "actor_2", "actor_8", "actor_3")
)

#create directed graph 
graph <- graph.data.frame(film_data, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)
plot(graph)
```

[image]

But R will still say that this graph is bipartite:

```
V(graph)$type <- V(graph)$name %in% film_data[,1]
 is.bipartite(graph)
[1] TRUE
```

You can further sabotage this graph by adding an extra link between two movies:

```
film_data <- data.frame(
    
    "movie" = c("movie_1", "movie_1", "movie_1", "movie_2", "movie_2", "movie_2", "movie_3", "movie_3", "movie_3", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_4", "movie_5", "movie_5", "movie_5", "movie_6", "movie_6", "actor_2", "movie_1"),
    "actor" = c("actor_1", "actor_2", "actor_3", "actor_2", "actor_3", "actor_4", "actor_1", "actor_5", "actor_6", "actor_2", "actor_7", "actor_1", "actor_8", "actor_5", "actor_9", "actor_3", "actor_2", "actor_8", "actor_3", "movie_2")
)

#create directed graph 
graph <- graph.data.frame(film_data, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)
plot(graph)
```

[image]

But R will still call it bipartite:

```
V(graph)$type <- V(graph)$name %in% film_data[,1]
is.bipartite(graph)
[1] TRUE
```

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong? Are these last two graphs actually bipartite? Or am I applying the code incorrectly?

Just to clarify: Are all undirected graphs cyclic? If you have a undirected graph with just one type of node, it it necessarily bipartite?

Thanks

Comment: Try `bipartite_mapping(graph)` instead

Comment: wow, great command! Just to clarify, does the bipartite_mapping() require you to first establish the type each vertex belongs to? e.g. V(graph)$type <- V(graph)$name %in% film_data[,1]

Comment: @MrFlick:  Are all undirected graphs cyclic? If you have a undirected graph with just one type of node, it it necessarily bipartite?

Comment: @Noob A graph is cyclic if it contains a cycle. That's not related to it being directed or undirected.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the graph you created is not bipartite: the part 'actors' has adjacent vertices.

The function `is.bipartite()` (or its name) is highly misleading. It only tells you if the graph has the required vertex attribute called type. It doesn't check the other characteristics of what makes a graph bipartite. Source: `?is.bipartite`